# start jupyter lab in different folder (windows)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

For jupyter notebooks, I can do:

```
jupyter notebook --ExtractOutputPreprocessor.enabled=False --notebook-dir C:/Bla
```

so I tried something similar for jupyter lab:

```
jupyter lab --app-dir C:/Bla
```

but get:

```
JupyterLab Error
JupyterLab application assets not found in "C:/Bla"
Please run `jupyter lab build` or use a different app directory
```

I did a few google searches without a clear answer. Could someone please enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `--app-dir` - this is for custom deployments of JupyterLab.

`notebook-dir` should work fine, as well as `ServerApp.root_dir`:

```
jupyter lab --notebook-dir C:/Bla
```

or

```
jupyter lab --ServerApp.root_dir C:/Bla
```

Unless you have a very old version of JupyterLab installed (in that case - upgrade).

Comment: thanks that looks almost right but I get popup that directory does not exist but maybe I can just ignore? Thanks.